# Google Chrome does not write a cookie on for site anymore

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome does not write the cookies for my site anymore. Cookies plays a great part for my joomla site to work. It works on FireFox and other browsers but not in Chrome. In other PC units, this does not happen but I am afraid that this might be a big problem experienced by my customers too.

My other sister sites works fine on Chrome except for the previous site.

Why does Chrome does not overwrite my cookies?

Where are the cookies stored for Chrome?

Have anyone experienced this king of problem?